# WkWebView unable to reset Cookies

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am having difficulties resetting or update the custom cookie after expired or missing the custom cookie in `decidePolicyFor navigationAction`. I have tried to reset the cookie in `decidePolicyFor navigationAction` function, it seems like not updating or unable to set a cookie.

Here is some of my code,

```
@IBOutlet weak var customWebView: UIView!
var webView : WKWebView!
var liveURL = "myLiveUrl"
let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
        .domain: "myLiveDomain",
        .path: "/",
        .name: "some name",
        .value: "some value",
        .secure: "TRUE",
        .expires: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10)
])
var isCookieReset : Bool = true
var urlrequestCurrent: URLRequest?

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.addWebView()
}

private func addWebView(){
    webView = WKWebView(frame: customWebView.bounds)
    webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie!)
    webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    customWebView.addSubview(webView)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.webView.load(URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: self.liveURL)!))
    }
}


func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

   webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { cookies in
           
   self.isCookieReset = true
            
   for cookie in cookies {
      if cookie.name.contains("some name") {
           self.isCookieReset = false
         }
   }
          
   if(self.isCookieReset == true) {
               
      if let currentrequest = self.urlrequestCurrent {
         if currentrequest == navigationAction.request {
            self.urlrequestCurrent = nil
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
         }
      }

      decisionHandler(.cancel)
                
      var customRequest = navigationAction.request
      webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(self.cookie!)
      self.urlrequestCurrent = customRequest
      self.webView.load(customRequest)
      return
   } else {
         decisionHandler(.allow)
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get cookie string in your decidePolicyFor using below method. You need to parse and store.

```
self.web.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies{ cookies in
//  print("==igcookies==: ", cookies)
for data in cookies {
   print(data)
}
}
```

If you want to delete all cookie from webview. Try below method will clear all cookies from you WKWebView.

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.removeCookies(since: Date.distantPast)
    WKWebsiteDataStore.default().fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { records in
        records.forEach { record in
            WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData(ofTypes: record.dataTypes, for: [record], completionHandler: {})
            print("Cookie ::: \(record) deleted")
        }
    }
    print("All cookies deleted")
}else{
    let cookieJar = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
    if let cookies = cookieJar.cookies{
        for cookie in cookies {
            cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.removeCookies(since: Date.distantPast)
}
```

**OR**

If you want to clear specific cookie. Here you need to set cookie value as blank.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                for cookie in (cookiestring!.split(separator: ";")) {
                    let data = cookie.split(separator: "=")
                    let userCookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
                        .version:1,
                        .domain: "www.yourhost.com",
                        .path: "/",
                        .name: data[0],
                        .value: "",
                        .secure: "TRUE",
                        .expires: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 31556926)
                    ])!
                      print("==userCookie== ", userCookie)
                    self.web.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(userCookie)
                }
            }
```

Hope it will help to fix your issue. Please have a look and let me know if anything is missing.

Comment: Let's say if I want to clear a specific cookie, should I just set back the same cookie name with value and new expiration date? Also, where should I place your suggested code? In my ````decidePolicyFor```` method? Moreover, where does the cookiestring comes from?

Comment: @Drew Have a look at my updated answer. Just use my suggested code when you want to change/reset cookie(s).